# How-to download Windows Process Activation Service (WAS)

Tags: windows, iis-7, download, was

I'm getting an error when I try to start an Application Pool in IIS7.

The error is called Service WAS was not found on computer'.'.'

I then googled "download Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) and I can't seem to find away to download it.

I'm running this on AWS on a remote desktop from my Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is included in Windows and no additional download is needed.

You need to open `Turn Windows features on or off` in Control Panel and install it from there.

Comment: Would that be in the IIS7 Manager?

Comment: No, there is an entry called Windows Process Activation Service

Comment: What specifically needs to be turned on or off to enable to install Windows Process Activation Service?

Comment: Thank you very much. I found it and installing it now!